# Excel BYROW sort result

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, excel-formula

I have got the following data:

[image: Initial data]

I have filtered the data to remove 0 values using the following:

```
=FILTER(AE11:AF33,BYROW(AF11:AF33,LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))>0)
```

I can't for the life of me sort this filter, my current output is:

[image: Current output]

But the output I want to achieve is:

[image: Desired output]

Any help on sorting this filter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wrap it all in the SORT formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SORT(FILTER(AE11:AF33,AF11:AF33>0),2,-1)` will do the filtering and sorting.

Second parameter of the SORT-function takes the column to sort by.

I don't think, that you need the LAMBDA function here

Comment: Thanks! I must have had a typo in my original formula as I tried this with no success *facepalm*